# How to get the Content of a XAML Button?

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

How do I get the Content of a XAML Button?

Visual Studio Community 15.9.4, with the C++/WinRT extensions installed.

I can set the Button's Content from the click handler, but cannot get the current Content.

Button definition from MainPage.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>
```

Click handler definition from MainPage.cpp:

```
void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const& sender, RoutedEventArgs const& args)
{
  myButton().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
}
```

I have also found that this code works to set the Content:

```
void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const& sender, RoutedEventArgs const& args)
{
  Button sendButton = winrt::unbox_value<Button>(sender);

  sendButton.Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
}
```

Code I have tried to get the Content just does not compile.

Comment: I did research the Button's Content property in the Microsoft on-line documentation.  It does indicate that I should be able to both get and set the Content, but nothing I have tried worked because it did not compile or, when examined, did not have the Content I was expecting, e.g., "Click Me" before the Button was clicked.  I also think that has to do with boxing and unboxing, but I am not sure how that applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In posting the original question, a thought was triggered, which I tried and which worked.  The following was added to the MainPage.cpp click handler:

```
IInspectable sendButtonContent = sendButton.Content();
hstring sendButtonString = unbox_value<hstring>(sendButtonContent);
```

When the code is paused, after the Button is clicked, the value of sendButtonString is "Clicked".